# Evitar scale com :hover em link dentro de uma <li>

Tags: css3

Tenho um código onde quero aplicar `scale` em todos os `<a>` e `<button>`, como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```css
body{
   background: #000;
}

#lista, #lista li{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   font-size: 20px;
}

#lista li{
   width: 25%;
   max-width: 100px;
   min-width: 70px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
   vertical-align: top;
}

#lista li a{
   color: #fff;
}

#lista li{
   -webkit-transition: color .1s ease;
   transition: color .1s ease;
}

#lista li img{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100px;
   max-height: 100px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   opacity: .9;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
   transition: transform opacity 2s ease;
}

#lista li:hover img{
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
   transition: transform opacity .1s ease;
}

a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #e8747d;
   display: inline-block;
}

a:hover{
   color: #FFFED3;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
}

button, a{
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
   transition: transform .1s ease;
   cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.18);
   transform: scale(1.18);
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista">
   <li>
      <a href="#">
         <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/47/Dracula_One_Sheet_Style_F.jpg/220px-Dracula_One_Sheet_Style_F.jpg">
         Título
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
<div style="background: gray;">
   <a href="#">Link qualquer</a>
   <button>Botão qualquer</button>
</div>
```

Funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que eu não quero que o texto "Título" que acompanha a imagem dentro do link no `<li>` sofra o `scale` (fique estática), apenas a imagem.

Já tentei usar `:not(#lista li a)` em alguns lugares mas sem sucesso. Acho que o caminho é usar esse `:not` em algum lugar, mas não consegui fazer.

Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Mas pq o título tem que ficar dentro da tag `a`??

Comment: É porque se eu clicar nele quero ir para o mesmo lugar que se clicar na imagem.

Comment: Sim, mas acho mais fácil clicar em uma imagem do que em um texto não?

Comment: Mas eu quero que o título também seja um link, não apenas a imagem.

Comment: Entendi, é nesta estrutura aí não vai ter como mesmo então, como o Hugo disse, o elemento filho está recebendo as mesmas propriedades do elemento pai, e não tem como removê-las.

Comment: Remover o `a:hover{` não resolve o problema ? Ou esse tem de funcionar mas não quando tem uma imagem também lá dentro ?

Comment: @Isac O `a:hover` é para pegar todos os `<a>`... Mas já consegui resolver colocando uma classe no `<a>` que não quero que seja afetado.

Comment: Pois, isso era exatamente o que eu ia sugerir que é bem simples e resolve pois acerta apenas naqueles que quer

Comment: @Isac Quer postar a resposta? Agora, o que não entendi foi o seguinte: com a classe funciona, mas não entendo porque `:not(#lista li a)` não funciona. Se quiser postar uma resposta explicando porque esse seletor não funciona seria bem-vinda.

Comment: Tanto quanto sei o problema tem a ver com hierarquia. A prova disso é que se trocar por algo simples com o `not` funciona. Experimente fazer `a:not(.desligado):hover { ...` e adicionar a classe desligado naquele que não quer o efeito.

Comment: @Isac foi isso que fiz.

Comment: A julgar por esta resposta [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084147/6087092](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084147/6087092) não me parece que seja possível, pelo menos por enquanto, isto é, utilizando apenas css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver colocando uma classe no `<a>` que não quero que seja afetado:

```
<a class="links" href="#">
```

Então altero o `a:hover` para `a:hover:not(.links)`.

```css
body{
   background: #000;
}

#lista, #lista li{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   font-size: 20px;
}

#lista li{
   width: 25%;
   max-width: 100px;
   min-width: 70px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
   vertical-align: top;
}

#lista li a{
   color: #fff;
}

#lista li{
   -webkit-transition: color .1s ease;
   transition: color .1s ease;
}

#lista li img{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100px;
   max-height: 100px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   opacity: .9;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
   transition: transform opacity 2s ease;
}

#lista li:hover img{
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
   transition: transform opacity .1s ease;
}

a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #e8747d;
   display: inline-block;
}

a:hover:not(.links){
   color: #FFFED3;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
}

button, a{
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
   transition: transform .1s ease;
   cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.18);
   transform: scale(1.18);
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista">
   <li>
      <a class="links" href="#">
         <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/47/Dracula_One_Sheet_Style_F.jpg/220px-Dracula_One_Sheet_Style_F.jpg">
         Título
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
<div style="background: gray;">
   <a href="#">Link qualquer</a>
   <button>Botão qualquer</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alguns efeitos CSS aplicados ao pai vc não consegue remover dos filhos. Como por exemplo `opacity` e `filters`, `blend-modes` etc.

No caso mais específico do `transform`, um opção é inverter o que foi aplicado no pai no filho, então se vc aplicou `scale-up` no pai vc faz um `scale-down` no filho. Nesse caso nom o `:not()` vc nao consegue tirar o efeito no filho, como vc mesmo já tentou.

Veja o exemplo com o seu codigo, mas para fazer funcionar precisei colocar o texto dentro de uma tag, no caso usei uma tag `p` para poder fazer a referencia no css

```css
        body{
   background: #000;
}

#lista, #lista li{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   font-size: 20px;
}

#lista li{
   width: 25%;
   max-width: 100px;
   min-width: 70px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
   vertical-align: top;
}

#lista li a{
   color: #fff;
}

#lista li{
   -webkit-transition: color .1s ease;
   transition: color .1s ease;
}

#lista li img{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100px;
   max-height: 100px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   opacity: .9;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
   transition: transform opacity 2s ease;
}

#lista li:hover img{
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
   transition: transform opacity .1s ease;
}

a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #e8747d;
   display: inline-block;
}

a:hover{
   color: #FFFED3;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
a:hover p{

   -webkit-transform: scale(0.91);
   transform: scale(0.91);
   margin: 0;
}
a p{
   margin: 0;
}

button, a{
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
   transition: transform .1s ease;
   cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.18);
   transform: scale(1.18);
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista">
   <li>
      <a href="#">
         <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/47/Dracula_One_Sheet_Style_F.jpg/220px-Dracula_One_Sheet_Style_F.jpg">
         <p> Título</p>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
<div style="background: gray;">
   <a href="#">Link qualquer</a>
   <button>Botão qualquer</button>
</div>
```

---

Exemplo simples do uso do `:not()`, repare que ao fazer o `hover` no a todos os p ficam vermelhos, mas `not(:first-child)` que continua com a cor inicial

```css
a:hover p:not(:first-child){
   color: red
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <p> Título 1</p>
   <p> Título 2</p>
   <p> Título 3</p>
   <p> Título 4</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado jovem mas ficou do mesmo jeito... :D

Comment: Uai aqui no Snippet só a imagem aumentou, o texto desloca um pouco pq a imagem empurra a tag P de baixo que tem o texto. Não sei pq não deu certo ai.

Comment: Creio que fazer scale-down não é uma boa porque o texto acaba tremendo tb. Mas obg, vou tentar algo aqui.

Comment: @sam sim esse problema de renderização da fonte com esses tipo de efeito é bem comum.  Se eu pensar em outra opção te falo

Comment: Votei -1 porque não atendeu a pergunta. Se melhorar eu mudo o voto ok! ;)